# Refills prescriptions and Tranferring Prescriptions. How should I approach this?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-relationship

I have some doubts I would like to clear.

We have two features on our website we would like to provide to our customers for dealing with prescription drugs.

One feature allows potential new customers to transfer their prescription drugs from their current providing pharmacy to our pharmacy.

Another feature allows current customers to refill their current prescriptions.

Prescriptions must be either transferred from previous provider or must have existed before they can refilled.

To achieve the prescription transfer portion, I have two tables, one called Customer (which contains customer personal info as well as current providing pharmacy name and phone number) and the other called Prescriptions. This table contains prescription info. customerId is on this table as Foreign key to customer table.

The code below inserts records into customer table and prescriptions table for customers transferring their prescriptions from one pharmacy to our pharmacy.

I am also aware that I need to perform a check to see if customer trying to transfer prescriptiosn already exists on our table. I have not done this yet but will.

My doubt is how to handle the Refill portion of this task.

Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that inserts Transferred prescriptions.

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim s As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\GCP.accdb")
    Try
        SetRowData()
        Dim table As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

        If table IsNot Nothing Then

            s = "INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName, LastName, MiddleInitial, DOB, Email_Address, Phone, Address, City, State, ZipCode, PharmacyName, PharmacyPhone) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql = "Select Max(custId) From Customer"
            'Response.Write(s)
            'Response.End()
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(s, con)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtfName.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtMI.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtLName.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtDOB.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtemail.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtphone.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtAddress.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtcity.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtstate.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtzip.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtpharmacyName.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtPharmacyPhone.Text)
            con.Open()
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.CommandText = sql
            ID = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                Dim txPrescription As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(1), String)

                If txPrescription IsNot Nothing Then

                    Try
                        s = "INSERT INTO Prescriptions(Prescription, custId) VALUES "
                        s += "('" & txPrescription & "', " & ID & ")"
                        'Response.Write(s)
                        'Response.End()
                        'Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("allstringconstrng").ConnectionString
                        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
                        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(s, conn)
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        conn.Close()


                        'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
                        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                        lblResult.Text = "Your Prescriptions Transfer Request has been sent. Prescription requests are normally processed within 24 hours!"

                        'Clear the form
                        txPrescription = ""
                        txtfName.Text = ""
                        txtMI.Text = ""
                        txtLName.Text = ""
                        txtDOB.Text = ""
                        txtemail.Text = ""
                        txtphone.Text = ""
                        txtAddress.Text = ""
                        txtcity.Text = ""
                        txtstate.Text = ""
                        txtzip.Text = ""
                    Catch

                        'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
                        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                        lblResult.Text = "Your record failed to save, please try again."

                    End Try

                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, you should look into [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: Side note, also take a look at parameterizing your `INSERT`s, or at **Bobby Tables** as it's more commonly known. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: So you're asking how to find a developer familiar with HIPAA compliance, prescription management, applicable rules and regulations for the jurisdiction(s) you serve, ... ? Or you just want a way to tie refill prescriptions back to the prior prescription?

Comment: @HABO, LOL. That was funny!

No, when a customer transfers his or her prescriptions and now wants to refill them, how do I refill it back to prior prescriptions, exactly.

Comment: Does each row in the `Prescriptions` table have a (defaulted in your sample code) `RefillOfPrescriptionId` (nullable) column? You could then `INSERT ... SELECT ...` to copy the the previous prescription row to create a new row with a new issue date, approval, ... .

Comment: @HABO, I am a bit lost, sorry.

If I will respond based what I understand.

Users can refill as many as 6 prescriptions at same time.

So, the way we have the markup is that user enters prescription, then hit the `Add Another Refill` button to enter another refill number. As stated, can do this up to 6 refills before submitting to the db. So, essentially, it will be 1 customer to many prescription transfers or refills.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Are you trying to make an existing prescription (row) turn into a refill of itself (Bad idea.) or create a new row that represents a refill of a prior prescription (Better idea.)?

Comment: @HABO, We have a page that contains two links. One link is to transfer prescription drugs from some pharmacy to ours. The other is to refill prescriptions that have run out.

They go to Transfer Prescriptions page to transfer the drugs they wish to transfer. That's code I posted above.

Now, the user says, one of those prescriptions has run out and I need to refill. From design point of view, how do I handle this setup so I don't create new customer or prescription records? Just use exsiting customer info to refill the customer's drugs.

The first page link